# Separate gradients for multiple series in highmaps

Tags: highmaps

I've been searching the forum for a question on separate gradients for highmaps and can't find one. Supply I have a map like the [highmaps categorized areas demo](https://www.highcharts.com/maps/demo/category-map).

But instead of flat colors for multiple series I want separate gradients? I.e. for UTC-1 I want one gradient from white to blue. For UTC-2 another gradient from white to red.

Is this possible? I.e. a separate color axis for each series?